# Dynamic axios request url in Vue 3 Composables

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup, composable

I've tried this and it worked:

```
    const posts = ref{[]}
    const urlEndPoint = 'posts'

    const getPosts = async () => {
           let response = await axios.get('/api/'+urlEndPoint)
              posts.value = response.data.data
          }
```

but that one is not dynamic. My goal is to make the `urlEndPoint` value reactive and set from the components

then i tried this:

```
const urlEndPoint = ref([])
```

but I don't know how to send the value of `urlEndPoint` constant back from the `component` to the `composables`.

I tried these in my component:

```
const urlEndPoint = 'posts'
```

and

```
const sendUrlEndPoint = () => {
        urlEndPoint = 'posts'
    }
```

but none worked.

is there a way to accomplish this goal? like sending the component name to urlEndPoint value in composable or any other simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a composable function named use `useFetch` :

```js
import {ref} from 'vue'
export default useFetch(){

   const data=ref([])

   const getData = async (urlEndPoint) => {
           let response = await axios.get('/api/'+urlEndPoint)
              data.value = response.data.data
          }

  return {
     getData,data
 }
```

in your component import the function and use it like :

```js
const urlEndPoint=ref('posts')
const {getData:getPosts, data:posts}=useFetch()

getPosts(urlEndPoint.value)
```

Comment: this one accomplished my goal at the first try.

Comment: The answer is confusing as it does create a ref urlEndPoint but then does not use it. Additionaly, you have to use urlEndPoint.value in the getData function, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann you're right, the `urlEndPoint` is not used, it should be removed or added  as parameter like `getPosts(urlEndPoint.value)`